# Are there possibilities that only a part of a statement is not true?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

Are there possibilities that only a part of a statement is not true?

For example, "I consider a man as tall," but he is not tall in reality then the statement ‘I consider a man as tall’ is not partially a fact because ‘tall’ is not a fact?

For another example, "I actually tried to be a president," but I’m not in reality a president, is only a part of a statement ‘I tried to be a president’ not true?

For the other example, I actually wish I would be a president, but I’m not actually a president, is only ‘I would be a president’ in ‘I wish I would be a president’ not true?

Comment: I think you need to do some basic reading(s) in logic and/or semantics before tackling/phrasing this in some terms others can comprehend. 'tall' would be a predicate in a first-order logic conception/semantics. It's not clear what you mean by "'tall' is not a fact". I don't think there are many approaches to semantics that would propose that because of Russell's paradox.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to read about epistemic logic if the distinction between what you "consider" (as in " I consider a man tall") and what "is" is important.

Comment: A fact is a "piece of reality", something of which the language speaks of. A sentence may express a fact.

Comment: Please clarify. All possible concepts, including sentences, have parts (e.g. subject and predicate; beginning and end; letters and spaces, etc.), and not all parts are facts. Following your conclusion, no possible sentence would be a fact.

Comment: Your terminology is confused.  Philosophers don't speak about literal sentences like you seem to think. Philosophers use the term proposition  to describe an IDEA to other humans by using sentences. What you are doing is closer to RHETORIC or Psychology. I think you already KNOW that your use of TALL is problematic. How TALL does one have to be to be TALL? You are the one using the term you KNEW to be ambiguous. You must define the context if you are communicating your ideas to others. If I use an ambiguous term then the burden is on me to define the context of discourse. The same rule for all

Comment: Hey everyone did you hear the news? I fixed the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I consider a man to be tall," is true iff I consider a man to be tall. The consideration might internally be false in case the man in question is not actually tall, so in that sense an untruth is part of a truth; but it's not clear what the implications of such are supposed to be.

Comment: I'm glad I answered the question but I still don't know what the question really is...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question clearly.

Anyway, since I made an attempt to answer your question you may read this one also.

We often say that something is a real/true fact. This means that what we consider is false, can be considered as facts. More over, The facts we consider as true can often be proved false from a different perspective.

**A fact is a statement that can be proven true or false.**

Iff this statement is true, false statements are also facts.

https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/dictionary/true-facts-and-false-facts/